# Using ZipArchive with PHP 8 and temporary files

Tags: php, php-ziparchive, php-8

PHP 8 changes how the "open" of a ZIP archive works and it is noted that:

> Using empty file as ZipArchive is deprecated. Libzip 1.6.0 do not accept empty files as valid zip archives any longer.

In the test code below the opening of the ZIP file named `$backupzip` works without error but the opening of the ZIP file names `$invoicezip` fails with the error:

> Deprecated: ZipArchive::open(): Using empty file as ZipArchive is deprecated on line 12

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
define('BACKUPDIR','E:\Database_Backups\\');
$backupfile = BACKUPDIR . date('Ymd') . '.zip';
$temp_file  = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'AW');

$backupzip  = new ZipArchive();
$invoicezip = new ZipArchive();

$backupzip->open($backupfile,ZipArchive::CREATE);  // <<<--- this works
$invoicezip->open($temp_file,ZipArchive::CREATE);  // <<<--- this fails
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The failure is being caused by the fact that the use of the `tempnam` function actually creates a zero byte file and that is what `ZipArchive::CREATE` is complaining about.

The solution was to `unlink` the temporary file created by `tempnam` before trying to use it. In the example in the question I simply added `unlink($temp_file);` immediately after `$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'AW');`.

The first few lines now look like this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
define('BACKUPDIR','E:\Database_Backups\\');
$backupfile = BACKUPDIR . date('Ymd') . '.zip';
$temp_file  = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'AW');
unlink($temp_file);
```

Comment: You can also use `ZipArchive::OVERWRITE` instead of `ZipArchive::CREATE`, so the temp file is never deleted.

Comment: Brilliant! Don't know how I missed that. Thank you. Much better than erasing a just created temporary file.

Answer (score -1):

You can also just append a ".zip" at the end of the file name, this way once the file is created you wont need to delete it nor overwrite it.

Comment: It does, it removes the Deprecation notice as well as removes the need to overwrite the file everytime.